# Find extrema of $f_a(x)=\vert x-a\vert^2$ on $\overline{B_1(0)}$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, intuition

Let $\overline{B_1(0)}\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ be the closed unit-sphere and $a\in\mathbb R^3$.

> Find all extrema of the function $f_a(x)=\vert x-a\vert^2$ on $\overline{B_1(0)}$  depending on $a$.

I need tips/hints how to approach such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a picture: you want to minimize/maximize the distance from $x$ to $a$. It is basically a plane problem, due to symmetry: draw the unit cirle and the point $a$. What is the point of the circle closest to $a$? And what is the farthest?

You'll have to distinguish three cases: (1) $a$ is inside the ball; (2) $a$ is on the boundary of the ball; (3) $a$ is outside the ball.

Comment: The case $a=0$ is a little special too (regarding the number of extrema).

Comment: If $a=0$, the function $f_0$ is constant on $\partial B_1(0)$, and hence there are infinitely many maxima. The point $x=0$ is of course the unique minimum of $f_0$.

Comment: In the case (1), I would find $B_\epsilon(a)$ which intersects with the unit sphere in one point $b$ $\Rightarrow$ min = distance from a to b; for the maximum value I would draw a line from $a$ to $b$ and the point $c=\text{line}\cap B_1(0)$ on the other side of the ball would be the maximum value.

Comment: In the case (3) I would find a ball $B_\epsilon(a)$ which touches the unit-sphere in one point $\Rightarrow$ this point is the minimum value ; for the maximum value I would consider the two points $d_1$ and $d_2$ to which I can find a tangent vector from $a$ to $d_{1,2}$ (of just extend the line from the minimum case and the intersection of that line with the opposite side of the unit-sphere would be the maximum distance, I don't know if that is allowed...). For case (2) I don't know...

Comment: Actually case (2) is nothing special. It is clear that $x=a$ becomes again the closest point to $a$, while you should take $x=-a$ to maximize $f_a$.

Comment: Is the rest of the above correct? How would I write a proof to this, I cannot take derivatives of that function and apply the usual routine for finding extrema.

Comment: You are in $\mathbb{R}^3$, of course you can take derivatives!

Comment: I would write the function as $f_a(x) = \begin{cases}(x-a)^2,  & \text{if $x\gt0$} \\ (-x-a)^2, & \text{if $x\le0$}  \\ \end{cases}$ to get rid of the modulus and take the derivatives which in both cases are $2x-2a$. Is this correct, and could I now go on with the standard method to calculate the extrema?

Comment: No, it is completely wrong! $|x-a|$ is the *norm* of $x-a$, you can't treat it as the absolute value of a real number! $$|x-a|^2=(x_1-a_1)^2+(x_2-a_2)^2+(x_3-a_3)^2.$$